# SQL Count Month Average and YTD Average

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I want to query Average of Month and combine with YTD Average, i Already did the Monthly average , but don't have clue for combining  YTD Average.

sqlfiddle, edited from Mr Avi Code

[sqlFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/119fd/6)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(order_month, 'MON-YY'), order_avg
  FROM (
    SELECT TRUNC("Dayofmonth", 'MM') AS order_month, AVG("Numbervalue") AS order_avg
      FROM RAW_AVG
     GROUP BY TRUNC("Dayofmonth", 'MM')
     ORDER BY order_month
)
```

Expected Result

| JAN-18  |   12.000000   | Average(Jan)

| FEB-18  |   13.423729   | Average(1-Jan to 28 Feb)

| MAR-18  |   13.476923   | Average(1-Jan to 6-Mar)

Schema

```
  CREATE TABLE RAW_AVG
    ("Dayofmonth" date, "Numbervalue" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('01-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('02-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('03-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('04-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('05-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('06-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('07-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('08-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('09-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('10-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('11-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('12-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('13-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('14-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('15-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('16-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('17-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('18-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('19-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('20-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('21-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('22-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('23-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('24-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('25-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('26-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('27-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('28-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('29-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('30-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('31-Jan-2018', 12)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('01-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('02-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('03-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('04-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('05-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('06-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('07-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('08-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('09-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('10-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('11-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('12-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('13-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('14-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('15-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('16-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('17-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('18-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('19-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('20-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('21-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('22-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('23-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('24-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('25-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('26-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('27-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('28-Feb-2018', 15)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('01-Mar-2018', 14)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('02-Mar-2018', 14)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('03-Mar-2018', 14)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('04-Mar-2018', 14)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('05-Mar-2018', 14)
    INTO RAW_AVG ("Dayofmonth", "Numbervalue")
         VALUES ('06-Mar-2018', 14)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

ANSWER
I got my expected result using this code below (modify Mr Avi Code).
 the '6-MAR-18' is to simulate sysdate.today()

```
    with Ungroup_AVG AS
    (
    select    lastday,
    Round(Avg(totalpermonth) over (order by lastday rows between unbounded preceding and 
    Current row),6) as Valuespermonth
    from (
      select
      --last_day("Dayofmonth") lastday
      CASE WHEN
          "Dayofmonth" = '6-MAR-18' AND "Dayofmonth" < last_day('6-MAR-18' ) OR "Dayofmonth">=  trunc(last_day('6-MAR-18')-1, 'mm')
          THEN
          --to_date('6-MAR-18','DD-MON-YY')
           "Dayofmonth"
          ELSE
          last_day("Dayofmonth") 
          END lastday,
      Avg("Numbervalue") totalpermonth
      from RAW_AVG
      group by last_day("Dayofmonth"), "Dayofmonth") z  )
    ,
    Last_dayofMonth as(
      select max(lastday) as "DATEA" from Ungroup_AVG group by TRUNC(lastday, 'MM')
      )
    ,AVGZ as(  
      SELECT lastday,MAX(Valuespermonth) FROM Ungroup_AVG GROUP BY lastday,TRUNC(lastday, 'MM')
      )
    select M.* from Last_dayofMonth L
    JOIN
    AVGZ M on L."DATEA"= M.lastday
      ;
```

Comment: This depends on how you want to calculate "YTD Average" - is it done "per day" or can it be done "per month"? Note: offering **sample data** (as text, not images) and the **expected result** would help get your question solved.

Comment: it is done "per day", thank for the advice, i'll do better next time when ask

Comment: You can do better right now, not when you ask a new question - you can edit your existing question to add in the sample input data and expected response. That will help us to help you much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like a rolling average per month to get your output. Since you have data on row basis you can do in the same way first, getting average per month and then getting rolling average for the whole year. Please note that there will be decimal difference if you do average all at once (like you have done in Excel) and then in SQL as first you need one row per month.

```
With Cte as (select to_date('01-Jan-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 15 as Numbervalue 
from dual 
union all 
select to_date('02-Jan-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 23 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('03-Jan-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 3 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('04-Jan-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 22 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('05-Jan-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 11 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('06-Jan-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 33 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('07-Jan-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 44 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('01-Feb-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 33 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('02-Feb-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 11 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('03-Feb-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 22 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('04-Feb-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 33 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('05-Feb-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 44 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('06-Feb-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 22 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('07-Feb-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 11 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('01-Mar-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 12 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('02-Mar-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 23 as Numbervalue from dual
union all 
select to_date('03-Mar-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 34 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('04-Mar-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 54 as Numbervalue from dual
union all 
select to_date('05-Mar-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 2 as Numbervalue from dual 
union all 
select to_date('06-Mar-18', 'DD-MM-YY') Dayofmonth, 12 as Numbervalue from dual)


select    lastday,
Round(Avg(totalpermonth) over (order by lastday rows between unbounded preceding and 
Current row),2) as Valuespermonth
from (
select  last_day(Dayofmonth) lastday, Avg(NumberValue) totalpermonth
from cte
group by last_day(Dayofmonth) ) z  ;
```

Explanation: Rows between unbounded preceding will take all the previous row and current row  and get the average until current row. So for Feb it will take Jan avg and feb, and for March it will take Jan, Feb and March average.

Output:

```
 LASTDAY    VALUESPERMONTH
 31-JAN-18  21.57
 28-FEB-18  23.36
 31-MAR-18  23.18
```

Comment: hi Mr Avi,thanks alot, I think your result for march, is  calculate 1 jan -31 March,  i post your code in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/119fd/5 . I think i will enhace your code by limiting the input  jan to february, and union it with average jan to  6-march

Comment: @amincahcepu I used your screenshot earlier to build this which you provided from Excel as my basis. Are there any changes required ?

Comment: if you still have the image, i mention the "today" rows, what i mean is to average 1 Jan to 6 March. maybe thats why the result for march is different

Comment: Hi Mr Avi, I already modified your code. You can see my schema and the code on Question. If I dont modify, the March Average will be 31-01-2018 12 |
28-02-2018 13.5 |
31-03-2018 13.666667|

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing what method you require:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR( order_month, 'MON-YY' )
  , order_avg
  , AVG( order_avg ) OVER () AS YTD_avg
FROM (
    SELECT
        TRUNC( "Date", 'MM' ) AS order_month
      , AVG( "NumberA" )      AS order_avg
    FROM RAW_AVG
    GROUP BY
        TRUNC( "Date", 'MM' )
    ORDER BY
        order_month
) d
```

or, perhaps:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR( order_month, 'MON-YY' ) AS Label
  , order_avg
FROM (
    SELECT
        TRUNC( "Date", 'MM' ) AS order_month
      , AVG( "NumberA" )      AS order_avg
    FROM RAW_AVG
    GROUP BY
        TRUNC( "Date", 'MM' )
    ORDER BY
        order_month
) d
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Total'
  , AVG( NumberA )
FROM RAW_AVG
```